# How to show just one line of text in paragraph with width 100% which is part of the table cell?

Tags: css, html, xhtml, html-table

I have an example:

```
<table class="border" style="width:100%">
<tr>
    <td style="width:30%" class="border p10">
        Test
    </td>
    <td style="width:70%" class="border p10">
        <p class="longText">
        Looong text Looong text Looong text Looong text Looong text Looong text Looong text Looong text
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
.longText {
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    width:100%
}

.border {border: solid 1px #ccc}
.p10 {padding: 10px}
```

You can try it here http://jsfiddle.net/rnwCw/20/

The problem is that the long text destroys the width of the cells (30% and 70%). If I set width for .longText to PX for example 200px so the table is OK. But I need that <P> takes 100% of the cell. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should apply `table-layout:fixed`:

```
table {
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

Please see fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hARt5/ Is this the result you wish to achieve? Now table rows have 30/70 proportion.

Comment: Yes! You saved my time! Have never user this css attribute. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

remove  `white-space:nowrap;` add `word-wrap` which helps to break line by word.

```
.longText {
    overflow:hidden; 
    text-overflow:ellipsis;width:100%;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the 100% will take the entire browser width depending on your monitor also. as mentioned you above use the table-layout:fixed
or
use the px instead of the % to fix your table on any monitor resolution